# Excel VBA How to find a minimum value from a list of json pairs?

Tags: json, excel, vba

```
   URL = "https://xxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.com/api/getPrice.php"
   objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
   objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
   objHTTP.send JSONStringSend
   result = objHTTP.responseText    
   Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(result)
   methodcount = Json("shipping").Count
```

Above is the code to get the response.

Below is the result I got.

```
{
               "shipping":[
           {
           "name":"Speedpost via Singapore Post",
           "price":27.6,
           "delivery":"15-25 days"
           },
           {
           "name":"Registered Airmail via Swiss Post",
           "price":5.89,
           "delivery":"10 - 25 Days delivery"
           },
           {
           "name":"Unregistered Airmail via Singapore Post",
           "price":2.27,
           "delivery":"12 - 45 Days delivery"
           },
           {
           "name":"Registered Airmail via SF ",
           "price":4.36,
           "delivery":"10 - 15 business Days delivery"
           },
           {
           "name":"HK DHL",
           "price":37.09,
           "delivery":"4 - 7 Days delivery"
           }
           ]
}
```

Got a list of shipping methods as a http object by API call. I want to select the cheapest method and write only the price into a cell.

How to find the minimum value from all of the key/value pairs?

Comment: Your JSON data is corrupt. At a minimum it is missing a closing `}`.

Comment: ok, editted. Thanks.

Comment: It is still unclear where the JSON data comes from and where it is stored. Is it retrieved via xmlhttp and is in .responseText? Is it in a TXT file? Is it in some other allocated memory? If you want to read and parse the data then it would be nice to know where it is.

Comment: It's an http obj and I use ParseJson to convert it to json.

Comment: check the answer at this link https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/640780-parse-json-excel-vba.html

Comment: I think I would discard the json conversion altogether and simply multi-regex the .responseText but that might depend on what else you have planned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the explanation in the comments

```
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(result)
Set shipping = Json("shipping") 
methodcount = shipping.Count
targetCell.Value=getMinPrice(shipping) 'Display the min Price in the cell you want.
```

And here's the function to get minimum price

```
Public Function getMinPrice(shipping as Variant)As Double 'Variant is nothing but a convenient VBA way to specify that the shipping argument could be of any type. 
    getMinPrice=10000000.0        ' Set initial minPrice
                                  'Iterate through each record in shipping list. For each loop rec is assigned the new set of price list record. The loop is run till all records are exhausted.
    For Each rec In shipping      'rec is nothing but a variable like i=0, So you can replace rec here and in the following statements with whatever you like
                                  'You could avoid using 'Val' function here, I put it as a precautionary measure
        If getMinPrice > Val(rec("price")) Then 'Check if new price is less the minimum we already have
            getMinPrice = Val(rec("price"))     'Set the new minimum Price.
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: @user3394010 does the solution work for you or let me know if you need any more explanation for the same.

Comment: Yes, your code works. I got 2.27 into a cell. Thanks a lot. Could you explain more? I'm not familiar with using Variant, rec.

Comment: I've put some comments to explain `Variant` and `rec`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not solution base on json api.
Just refer to it(If your data is all as above content).

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    s = Range("a1") '<~~  if your json text in range("a1") else enter json instead
    's = json.text
    JsonToArray Range("b1"), s, "price"
    JsonToArray Range("c1"), s, "name"
    JsonToArray Range("d1"), s, "delivery"
    JsonToArrayMin Range("a4"), s, "price"
End Sub
Sub test2()
    Dim s As String
    s = Range("a1") '<~~  if your json text in range("a1") else enter json instead
    JsonToArrayMin Range("a4"), s, "price"
End Sub
Sub JsonToArray(rng As Range, Json As String, Item As String)
    Dim vR() As Variant, vSplit, v
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    Item = Item & Chr(34) & ":"
    vSplit = Split(Json, Item)
    For i = 1 To UBound(vSplit)
        v = vSplit(i)
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
        vR(n) = Split(v, ",")(0)
        vR(n) = Replace(vR(n), Chr(34), "")
        vR(n) = Replace(vR(n), ":", "")
        vR(n) = Replace(vR(n), "}", "")
        vR(n) = Replace(vR(n), "]", "")

    Next i
    If n > 0 Then
        rng.Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End If
End Sub

Sub JsonToArrayMin(rng As Range, Json As String, Item As String)
    Dim vR() As Variant, vSplit, v
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    Item = Item & Chr(34) & ":"
    vSplit = Split(Json, Item)
    For i = 1 To UBound(vSplit)
        v = vSplit(i)
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
        vR(n) = Split(v, ",")(0)
        vR(n) = Replace(vR(n), Chr(34), "")
        vR(n) = Replace(vR(n), ":", "")
        vR(n) = Replace(vR(n), "}", "")
        vR(n) = Replace(vR(n), "]", "")
        vR(n) = Val(vR(n))
    Next i
    If n > 0 Then
        rng = WorksheetFunction.Min(vR)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I will try your code soon and tell you if it works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, your code works. Although I do not completely understand all of them. I will try to learn them when I have time. Thanks.